# PyMODM - Find Document(s)

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, pymodm

I'm using PyModm as an ORM layer for MongoDB for my Django CRUD app.

I created a MongoModel as in so:

```
class Book(MongoModel):
    title = fields.CharField(primary_key=True)
    author = fields.CharField()
```

To create and update documents the pymodm API is really good, but I couldn't find an easy way to retrieve one or more documents, as Book.object.all() returns a QuerySet that seems to be only Json-serializable when iterating over it.

So the workaround I found is

```
books = []
for book in Book.objects.all():
    books.append({
        'title': book.title,
        'author': contact.author
    })
return JsonResponse(books)
```

And for retrieving one book by it's primary-key:

```
for book in Book.objects.raw({'_id': title}):
    book = {
        'author': book.author,
        'title': book.title
    }
return JsonResponse(book)
```

However, this seems not a very sufficient nor pretty way. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [`values()`](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html#pymodm.queryset.QuerySet.values) will help:

```
books = list(Book.objects.values().all())
book = Book.objects.values().get({'_id': user_id})
```

Comment: Yeah ok this is awesome it works. It returns a dict also with a _cls property (project.mongoModels.Book) but I see you can filter it out as in so:
Book.objects.only('title', 'author').values().get({'_id': 'asd'})